# Membership Expiration Date Report Filter is Ignored

Tags: civimember, civireport

In CiviCRM membership reports, the Membership Expiration Date filter is ignored, and all records are returned no matter what parameters you try.  We started experiencing this around CiviCRM 5.11.  We are currently on CiviCRM 5.21.3 on Drupal 7.7.3.  Seems odd that no one else appears to have reported this after many months.

[image: Screenshot of filter results]

Comment: NOTE - there have been 2 security releases and 1 for ESR (if that is what you are on) since 5.21

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on [dmaster](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/22) ie 5.32 which is always a good way to test something before flagging it as it may already have been fixed :-)

I get

[image: this]when I apply

[image: this filter]

compared to [image: this]

when I apply no filter

I don't know which specific report you mean, but good if you can test on dmaster and then if there is still an issue, report back here and we can help confirm if it is a bug. hope that helps you

Comment: I added a screen shot above of what we are seeing.  It does work as expected on the demo site.  I will update to 5.27.7 and see if that helps, but it might be a quirk particular to our system.